# PTIJ: Paddy's Purim Partying Problem

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Purim falling [on March 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Patrick%27s_Day) this year raises the question: May a person count a single act of getting drunk as celebrating *both* the Jewish festival and the Irish festival?  Or do Irish Jews need to get drunk twice, with a period of sobriety in between?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: If the answer is separate, Is the minchag Dublin 72 minutes, 3 hours, into the 6th hour, or 6 hours?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. Unfortunately it does not suffice as we have the rule of "אין מערבין שמחה בשמחה" (e.g. see [Mishneh Torah, Ishus 10:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Marriage.10.14?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - "Do not mix one happy occasion with another" - so you have to go again! Hiccup!

Comment: If you only drink on the night of the 16th and the night of the 17th, you avoid all safek as to which one you drank for.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to clarify with the Irish if they also have "Shushan st. p..k day" like we have for Purim. If it's a yes, the question is compounded.

Now if you take in to consideration sefeyka diyoma as by other Jewish holidays, one would also need to drink on the 16th.

By extension to the above, one may not know if they are drinking on the 15th due to Shushan Purim or sefeyka diyoma so they might want to split it to two days and push one off to the preceding Monday or Thursday as like the reading of the Megilah see daf 2a in the mishna.

This, of course, will cause one to be drinking the majority of the week, the principal robo kekulo (רובו ככולו) so one will need to drink the whole week!